# R210 vs R210II rails

Tags: dell

I have an R210II (Service tag 8C04HY1), which unfortunately does not have rails that I need.

I've found rack rails at https://www.dell.com/en-nz/work/shop/dell-readyrails-1u-static-rails-for-2-4-post-racks/apd/770-bbif/networking for an R210 server.  Does anyone know if these will work with an R210II server?

FYI, according to the Parts list on my server, the rails my server originally shipped with were described as:

770-11333 : 2-Post/4-Post 1U Static Rails, Short
Part Number     Description     Quantity
HKNKW   MOD,RCKRL,2/4PST,1U,STAT,SHT    1
JWFR6   KIT,RCKRL,2/4PST,1U,STAT,SHT    1

Comment: I thought this would be an easy question to answer by looking through the Dell catalogue and... wow. I'm stumped. I see random forum posts saying R310 rails will work for the R210ii but I would take that with a grain of salt. It looks like Dell never sold sliding rails with this server, only static rails and rack ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to someone from Dell today.  The R210 and R210 II use the same rail kit - Dell part 770-BBIF / part code W625M.